# what is the error in the following mysql statement

Tags: mysql

What is this error in MYSQL statment

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO stores(name, store_type, hours, rating_txt, rating_star, address_id) VALUES (".$name.",".$store_type.",".$hours.",".$rating_text.",".$rating_star.",".$address_count.")"))

Comment: -1 for not providing the error, lack of formatting, basic Google search

Comment: @kermit...first time when i ran it, i hardly got any error...lol....but ur doing well!!

Answer (score 1):

variable need to be inside single quotes.

change `".$name."`

into

`'".$name."'` or or `'.$name.'` or  `'$name'`

Comment: I'd go for the one without dots. They're so over-rated

Comment: @Strawberry sure, just to show the 3 possibilities

Comment: INSERT INTO stores(name, store_type, hours, rating_txt, rating_star, address_id) VALUES ('$name','$store_type','$hours','$rating_text','$rating_star','$address_count')") -- is this correct???

Comment: INSERT INTO 
 stores(
        name, 
        store_type, 
        hours, 
        rating_txt, 
        rating_star, 
        address_id) 
VALUES ('$name',
        '$store_type',
        '$hours',
        '$rating_text',
        '$rating_star',
        '$address_count')

Comment: @ Vickel that seems to sorted but i am getting syntax error on $mysql_query in this statement.... $result = $mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS addressCount from address");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $address_count=$row['addressCount'];   what i really want is the count number....can't believe life is so difficult, for such a simple thing...lol

Comment: @vinodhBarnabas check this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257217/php-mysqli-how-do-i-count-query-result-rows

Comment: I got it done using mysqli_insert_id($con)

Answer (score 0):

You should sanitize your input values, i.e. use prepared statements.
If you only use mysqli_real_escape_string for sanitizing you need to quote (most) values.
You've got one closing bracket too much.