# How do I find the total number of results in a db table with SQL and PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I want to get the total count of the users in the table 'users'.  I think I've got the SQL command right, I just can't figure out how to use PHP to stick that total into a variable.  I'm trying to avoid using PDO and just sticking with procedural mysqli.

```
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 $total = mysqli_num_rows($result)???
```

I want to use the $total variable for pagination in my website.  I'm sure this question has been asked many times in here, but I can't find a solution using mysqli procedural.  Thank you.

Comment: read this this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257217/php-mysqli-how-do-i-count-query-result-rows

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the SQL command isn't correct, you'd need to select all the users in the table or all the users that match your criteria. Then you'd have to use the MySQLi built it function [num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$total = $result->num_rows;
```

That number of users are now stored in `$total`.