# Count number of record by equal value in MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, backend, php-7.1

I use  `Php-7.1` `MySQLi` extension.

How properly count all exist equal records from `tab` records to get amount: `3`, as `num` column contains `3` records of `9837` value by `IDs`: `2`, `5` and `7` or just count number of equal records, because final desired result is a total number of equal record without `IDs` from `MySql` database  about 10000 records:

```
ID | num  | 
-----------
1  | 7767 | 
2  | 9837 | 
3  | 4532 | 
4  | 5643 | 
5  | 9837 | 
6  | 5463 | 
7  | 9837 | 
8  | .... |
```

Comment: See [num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) or MySQL's [count()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP, MySQLi - How do I count query result rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257217/php-mysqli-how-do-i-count-query-result-rows)

Comment: Show expected result to us

Answer (score 1):

To get the full list of unique values and count them, do:

```
$query = "SELECT num, count(num) FROM tab group by num 
  order by count(num) desc";
```

This will simply return an ordered list of all unique num in the table, in order from most frequent to least frequent.