# How can I tell the user if there is no data in database for particular date that input by the user

Tags: php, mysql

i'm doing a report system that can collect the data from the database and display it to the user. User is required to enter the date to view the data for that particular day. There will be certain day that do not have any data in the database. So i want to tell the user that there is no record in the database for the date they input, what should i do with my code?

This is the code for date search(daily.html):

```
<form action="viewdailyreport.php" id="view" method="post">
<table>
<tr><th>Select Date to View Report: </th><td><input type="date" id="date" class="datepicker" name="date" value="date" required></td></tr>
<tr><td><br></td><td><br></td></tr>
<tr><td><br></td><td><br></td></tr>
<td> </td><td><input type="submit" class="button" value="View"></td>
</table>
</form>
```

viewdailyreport.php:

```
echo "<table class='report' style='background-color:white;'>";
        echo "<tr >";
        echo "<th>Date</th>";
        echo "<th>Driver id</th>";
        echo "<th>Driver name</th>";
        echo "<th>Vehicle id</th>";
        echo "<th>Vehicle model</th>";
        echo "<th>Booked services</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

            echo "\t<tbody><tr>
                    <td>".$row['Booking_date']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['Driver_id']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['Driver_name']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['Vehicle_id']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['Vehicle_model']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['Booking_service_type']."</td>

                    </tr></tbody>\n";

        }
    echo "</table>";
```

i expect that when user searches for the date that do not have any record in database, it will prompt a message telling user that there is no record.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP, MySQLi - How do I count query result rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257217/php-mysqli-how-do-i-count-query-result-rows)

Comment: `if(!mysqli_num_rows($result)) { echo "No entries for that date"; }`

Comment: I would not write an `echo` for every line in your `viewdailyreport.php`. Do a multi line `echo` like you did in the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Right now it will just don't go through the iteration since it has no items to iterate over of course. To give the user a message when there are no results you could use the `mysqli_num_rows()` function. It will return an `integer`.

---

In your case something like this would fit

```
if( ! mysqli_num_rows($result) )
{
  echo 'Couldn\'t find any rows.';
}
```